# libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll need 32 and 64 Bit simultaneously

Tags: delphi, indy

I use Delphi Seattle and my application has one 32Bit Exe and another 64Bit Exe.
For certain operations like MS Graph API I need these DLL's (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll).
Both Dll's have the same names, how can I ensure my Exes use the matching Bit's DLL.
All my work is in a single folder

I was hoping the 64 bit dll's would not have the name as ...32.dll

Comment: Start using question marks when formulating questions (thumb of rule: if it contains "how", it's most likely a question, not a sentence). Then throw away those outdated SSL versions. Most obvious solution is to just use one sub folder to keep them all apart - I wonder how you solved the problem that both your EXEs can't have the same name...

Comment: Put the DLLs in sub directories so they can have the same names, and access them using an assembly named in the application manifest.

Comment: Thanks David but will use Remy's solution as it is single liner and worked straight off.@AmigoJack will keep the "?" in mind thanks. Regarding Exe, obviously they are different Exe's with different names and functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the 32bit and 64bit DLLs in the same folder, since their filenames will clash, as you noted.  So, put them in different folders instead, and then at runtime you can have each EXE call Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to tell Indy which folder to load the DLLs from.